# How to extract logic out of a model into a more generic way for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I suppose this is related to "Plain Old Ruby Objects"

I built the following method for a "log_entry" model:

```
  def parse_time(string)
    parts = string.split(":").map(&:to_f)
    parts = [0] + parts if parts.length == 2
    hours, minutes, seconds = parts
    seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    seconds.to_i
  end
```

I'd like to extract this into a plain old ruby class and then use this method as neccesscary in the rails log_entry model class.

Where would I put this class, and how would I test it in rspec just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make method like this in Ruby on Rails. It is just converting the time(string) in number of seconds.

You can use `Time.parse("23:01").seconds_since_midnight`

If you need to use to quickly have such converion in views/controllers, you can add helper methods for that as:

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
def parse_time(string)
  Time.parse(string).seconds_since_midnight
end
helper_method :parse_time
```

Comment: I'm getting "3600.0" how do I get rid of the leading .0?

Comment: I did return "%0.f" % string but not sure how pretty that is.

Comment: `Time.parse(string).seconds_since_midnight.to_i` ?