# How to format time from seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have the following:

```
LogEntry.format_time(3600).should eql("01:00:00")
```

How to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail, background information?

Comment: You just asked similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268372/how-to-extract-logic-out-of-a-model-into-a-more-generic-way-for-rails, both have ambiguous information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in your LogEntry model.

```
class LogEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  #your properties and attributes
  def self.format_time(seconds)
    Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea this existed.